# Multiple server client

Tags: c#

I am creating a network monitoring tool that allows the the user to shut down computers and do basic tasks over a tcpip connection. I am looking into the best way to go about this. I want to create a dashboard style page that shows all of the computers that are able to be shutdown by the software.

I be-leave the best way to achieve this is to have a server on each pc I want to shut down and have 1 client that will connect to all of them and show there status.

At this point i have hit a road block... I'm new to tcpIP programming and am unsure on how to accomplish what I want to do. I want to preform basic tasks on each computer seppretly from my dashboard.

all of which needs to be programmed in C#.

dose anyone have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve by C#,
All you have to do it write one utility with program for shutdown etc.
Deploy this utility in each windows m/cs which you want to monitor.
Now connect all this system to your server (One m/c in which you will monitor all the system).
In the main m/c you need to deploy the dashboard application, this dashboard application with connect to all m/c in which your earlier utility is deployed.

Below mentioned video somehow help you for code to shutdown the m/c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-W1ZjddS10

You will connect all m/c by using LAN IP or by computer name and make sure your client application is running in free port.

All the best.